# Sending Data From Delegate View To Delegated View [Objective-C]

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, delegates

So I am trying to learn how to send data from one view controller to another.

My code thus far takes the data entered from one VC (`DelegateVC`) and displays it in a label on another VC(`ViewController`).

Here the delegate is `ViewController` and the delegated is `DelegateVC`.

===========================================================================

## Main Question

But what if I want to pass the data of the label from `ViewController` to `DelegateVC`? How can I accomplish this? I tried engineering the same concept of delegates but with the `DelegateVC` as the delegate of `ViewController`. Not sure if this is the write approach.

## TL;DR:

In `VC`, if I hit `Next View`, I go to `DelegateVC` and enter "test", it will show up in `VC's receiving label` as "test".

Now the next time I hit `Next View`, I want the existing label's value to show up in the `TextField` of `DelegateVC`. Instead of a blank `TextField`, there will be the value "test".

===========================================================================
Let's say I have a `Main.storyboard` like so:

[image: description]
I have a `ViewController.h` file as:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController


@end
```

**`ViewController.m`:**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "DelegatedVC.h"

@interface ViewController () <MainVCDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *receivingLabel;
- (IBAction)nextView:(id)sender;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (IBAction)nextView:(id)sender {

}

-(void) sendBackData:(DelegatedVC *)delegatedVC :(NSString *)textField {
    [delegatedVC dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    self.receivingLabel.text = textField;
}
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    DelegatedVC *secondVC = segue.destinationViewController;
    secondVC.delegate = self;
}
@end
```

**`DelegateVC.h:`**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@protocol MainVCDelegate;

@interface DelegatedVC : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *sendDataTF;
- (IBAction)sendData:(id)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) id<MainVCDelegate> delegate;
@end

@protocol MainVCDelegate <NSObject>
-(void) sendBackData: (DelegatedVC *) delegatedVC : (NSString *) textField;
@end
```

**`DelegateVC.m:`**

```
#import "DelegatedVC.h"
@protocol MainVCDelegate;

@interface DelegatedVC ()

@end

@implementation DelegatedVC

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

- (IBAction)sendData:(id)sender {
    [self.delegate sendBackData: self : _sendDataTF.text];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A delegate allows one object to send messages to another object when an event happens.

In your case to pass data of label from `ViewController` to `DelegateVC`, you do not need to use delegate. But since you want to update `receivingLabel` when changing happens on `sendDataTF` textfield , in this case you need a delegate and I think you have done it well.

**Solution**: You need to declare a property in `DelegateVC` to store passing string from `ViewController` and set that text in `sendDataTF` on `viewDidLoad`.

Declare a property in **DelegateVC.h:**

```
@interface DelegatedVC : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) id<MainVCDelegate> delegate;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *labelString;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *sendDataTF;

- (IBAction)sendData:(id)sender;

@end
```

Pass receivingLabel text in **ViewController.m:**

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender           
{
   DelegatedVC *secondVC = segue.destinationViewController;
   secondVC.delegate = self;
   secondVC.labelString = self.receivingLabel.text;
}
```

Set labelString in **DelegateVC.m:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  self.sendDataTF.text = self.labelString;
}
```

Hope it will work.

Answer (score 3):

> But what if I want to pass the data of the label from ViewController
>   to DelegateVC? How can I accomplish this?

So you're doing the delegation right as I can see in your code. Back to your main question, you just need to declare a public `NSString` object in your `DelegateVC.h`, and then access that and pass the data to that from your `ViewController`'s `prepareForSegue`.

Next step, in your `DelegateVC.m`, get your `NSString` object's value and pass it to your `UITextField`.

Let me know if this helps :)

Comment: I tried this but didn't work. What I did was in `DelegateVC.h` declared `static NSString *globalStr`. In `ViewController`'s `prepareForSegue`, I added `globalStr = _receivingLabel.text`. Finally, in `DelegateVC.m`'s `viewDidLoad` I added `_sendDataTF.text = globalStr`. Thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: That's what I'm telling you in my answer above :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is proper working code you can have a look at :

DelegateVc.h File with Label and button

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "DelegatedVC.h"

@interface DelegateVC : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *ReceiveLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *NextView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *TextFeildText;
```

DelegateVC.m File With segues

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    _ReceiveLabel.text = _TextFeildText;
}
- (IBAction)NextViewBtnAction:(id)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ToDelegated" sender:sender];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ToDelegated"])
    {
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        DelegatedVC *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        vc.LabelText = _ReceiveLabel.text;

        // Pass any objects to the view controller here, like...

    }
}
```

DelagatedVc.h with textfield

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "DelegateVC.h"

@interface DelegatedVC : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *RCTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *SenddataBtn;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *LabelText;
@end
```

DelagatedVc.m with Segue

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    _RCTextField.text = _LabelText;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (IBAction)SendDataBtnAction:(id)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ToDelegate" sender:sender];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ToDelegate"])
    {
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        DelegateVC *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        // Pass any objects to the view controller here, like...
        vc.TextFeildText = _RCTextField.text;


    }
}
```

My storyBoard Outlook

[image]

Comment: Rather than use a segue back to the original view controller, it would be better to use an unwindSegue so your not stacking views on top of each other. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2298/_index.html